# How does `pyspark.sql.functions` hold the state of some dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am starting to read about pyspark while I have no prior experience in Spark.

I found some examples like: `df.select(col("gender") == "m").show()` but I can not understand how this is feasible from Python perspective.

Things I am sure about:

- `df` holds data, so it is an object of some class with data as a main state (conversely).
- `Select` a is method in the same class, here acting on its data (df object)
- `df.select` could return some object (normal, I know how is chaining generally implemented) , So again `Show` is called later, all is fine.
- `col("gender") == "m"` *resolves to a boolean but that is it and nothing more!!!!!*

My question is how `col("gender")` could return anything related to our data while it is a function with a simple String as input !

ps; I also remember seeing these using Pandas before.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> col("gender") == "m" resolves to a boolean but that is it and nothing more!!!!!

This is the part that is incorrect.
`col(a)` function returns a Column object with an instruction to look at the column named "a" in the DataFrame.

```
col("a")
>> Column<'a'>
```

while `col("a") == 10` function returns a Column object as well with some spark magic of what to do.

```
col("a") == 10
>> Column<'(a = 10)'>
```

This can be done in python by setting an `__eq__` function in the Column class that returns a Column object and not a True/False boolean response.

The `.select` function takes the **Column** and together they return what you asked for.

Comment: I can understand that `__eq__` is overloaded, but how in that magic there is a reference to the "current" dataframe, which is not directly referenced (like `col("a", df) == 10` for instance). But ty anyway I see it is around this idea.

Comment: the `.select` function is a class method of the relevant DataFrame.
so think you have a select clause that accepts a col("a"), it knows what DataFrame to search and the input is which column to select.

Comment: true how i missed that .